# Adding library to NDK project - eclipse

Tags: android, android-ndk, box2d, liquidfun

Eclipse NDK, NativeActivity project. 
I ma trying to add a liquidfun(Box2D) library to my existing project. Unfortunately, no one in internet explain how to precisely do. 
I'am stuck after building library using ndk (following this https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html), and run sample project. I have totally no idea how to use it in my own project. 
My **Android.mk**, i already using sfml.

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := sfml-example


PROJECT_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/CPP/*.cpp)
PROJECT_FILES := $(PROJECT_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp 

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(PROJECT_FILES)

FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)*.cpp)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sfml-system
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += sfml-window
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += sfml-graphics
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += sfml-audio
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += sfml-network
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sfml-main

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,sfml)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have some prebuild libraries in my own project, and i include them like:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libcurl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcurl.a
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcares libssl
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/curl/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

this is for prebuilt static library (with .a extension). If you would like to include shared, just change it to `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`.
This file to include is inside `MyProject/jni/lib/{arch}` folder (with other libraries) and header files of library are put inside `MyProject/jni/curl/include` (just like it is visible in `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` variable)

the names you pass to `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` must be same as one that are declared in `LOCAL_MODULE` of other libraries/modules.

also everything you will probably need you can find in NDK docs that are in NDK folder. For prebuilt libraries there is separate section.